# Converting java class to groovy: Groovy:No expression for the array constructor call

Tags: java, groovy, syntax

For testing purposes I would like to try and use the below java class. But I need it to be ported to groovy.

The java class:

```
public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context != null ? context.getSocketFactory() : null);
    }
}
```

When I just move that to a .groovy file I get the following errors on this line:

```
private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};
```

Error:

```
Groovy:No expression for the array constructor call at line:
```

And this line:

```
if (trustManagers == null) {
    trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()}; 
}
```

Error:

```
Groovy:No expression for the array constructor call at line:
```

This first line I have ported like this:

```
  private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = [ new X509Certificate(){} ] as X509Certificate[]
```

Not 100% sure its correct though. But I still have an error on the second line:

```
    trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We cannot use Java array initialization syntax in Groovy.

So

```
private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = [ new X509Certificate(){} ] as X509Certificate[]
```

is correct
and you also need to change

```
trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
```

to

```
trustManagers = [new HttpsTrustManager()] as TrustManager[];
```

Comment: I have another situation here , where i want to initialize the array in groovy with a bean.getXxx() method. Can you please help by giving the syntax.

Comment: modifiedScanner.setIncludes( new String[] { sqljFile.getName() } ) my existing java  code

Comment: try: modifiedScanner.include = [sqljFile.name] as String[]